# Correct way to start a map activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, architecture, fragment

I want to start as `MainActivity` a `MapActivity` and include inside a menu fragment and some more stuff. My dilemma is what would be better, make my `MapActivity` as main or make another activity with the map and include it inside an empty `MainActivity` where I will put more stuff later?

Comment: In your answer you didn't respect the Architecture of Androidx. I found a solution but isn't yours, thanks for the answer and I give you a positive mark. ;)

Answer (score 1):

make your main activity your map activity, MainActivity is really just a name for a class and can be entirely removed or changed, it doesn't have any special meaning, so if the main point of your app is to use maps, make your map activity your main activity.